# Microsoft Solitaire Collection execution corrupts graphical redraw?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

Seeing a very peculiar issue where when running Microsoft Solitaire Collection on Windows 10 with the most recent updates (as of 7 Nov 16), there are graphical anomalies and redraw behavior.  Has anyone else seen this?

To clarify: *This does not happen unless I run this Windows Store game.*

To elaborate, here are a couple examples, the first of which is a short screencast to demonstrate how icons do not highlight after app termination:
[**Example Screencast of Icons**](https://cl.ly/2a2I1J1S0p44)

Continuing on, note here that after this some windows also have a transparency issue where no contents or controls are drawn:
[image: transparent window]

The only way to force a window such as this to respond properly is to try to click or use the keyboard to activate control elements, otherwise the window does not refresh with content.

Comment: Have you updated your display drivers?

Comment: Yes. No joy. Even reverted to older ones.

Comment: Solved this by installing kb3200970. Will add it as an answer once the system allows.

Comment: Sounds like it was pure luck that kb3200970 fixed it.  The issues it resolved wouldn't have caused your problem